# How to disable toolbar on window extjs component autoEl iframe

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

So viewer can't download or print it.

this the code ::

```
function showsFiles(file) {
    var fileWindow = Ext.create('widget.window', {
        closeAction: 'hide',
        resizable: true,
        autoScroll: true,
        frame: false,
        border: false,
        constrain: true,
        modal: false,
        width: 800,
        height: 500,
        maxHeight: 850,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'component',
                autoEl: {
                    tag: 'iframe',
                    style: 'height: 100%; width: 100%; border: none',
                    src: "<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/upload/" + file
                }
            }
        ],
        layout: {
            align: 'fit'
        }
    });
    fileWindow.setTitle(".:  File " + file + ":.");
    fileWindow.show();
}
```

Comment: `src: "<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/upload/" + file + '#toolbar=0&navpanes=0'` would at least work for PDF embeds... while this questions lacks one relevant detail: the kind of content within the iFrame.